# VBA - How to apply Regular Expression Matching in VBA Data Validation formula

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am trying to use regular expression matching in VBA for data validation.
There is a column of data in the Excel sheet that a user is editing. If it is not in the correct format (ex: AB \d+), there will be an error message, and the user will not be able to enter that data.

The regular expression code is from [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/regex-match-excel/) and can be used in Excel to check if a cell or range value matches the expression correctly. However, when the same function (RegExpMatch) is used for Formula1 in data validation, it is giving the error "Type mismatch". When the function is used in cells in Excel, it does return TRUE or FALSE as expected. Also, when I use the data validation UI tool in excel, it is working as expected. The issue arises only in VBA; this preferably should not be done with the data validation tool.

RegExpMatch takes in a range and returns a range, but the validation formula needs a string, so I had come up with another approach that does return a string. However, the second approach is evaluating only one cell and basing the formula for the entire range on the result for one cell.
Questions

- Can RegExpMatch be called with a single cell the same way that EXACT can be called with a single cell?
- Is there an easier way to use regular expression matching in data validation in vba?

Reg Exp Match function

```
Public Function RegExpMatch(input_range As Range, pattern As String, Optional match_case As Boolean = True) As Variant
  Dim arRes() As Variant 'array to store the results
  Dim iInputCurRow, iInputCurCol, cntInputRows, cntInputCols As Long 'index of the current row in the source range, index of the current column in the source range, count of rows, count of columns

  On Error GoTo ErrHandl

  RegExpMatch = arRes

  Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  regex.pattern = pattern
  regex.Global = True
  regex.MultiLine = True
  If True = match_case Then
    regex.ignorecase = False
  Else
    regex.ignorecase = True
  End If

  cntInputRows = input_range.Rows.count
  cntInputCols = input_range.Columns.count
  ReDim arRes(1 To cntInputRows, 1 To cntInputCols)

  For iInputCurRow = 1 To cntInputRows
    For iInputCurCol = 1 To cntInputCols
      arRes(iInputCurRow, iInputCurCol) = regex.Test(input_range.Cells(iInputCurRow, iInputCurCol).Value)
    Next
  Next

  RegExpMatch = arRes
  Exit Function
ErrHandl:
    RegExpMatch = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Data Validation function

```
    For Col = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       
        If Cells(1, Col).Value = "Fruit" Then
            With Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(1048576, Col)).Validation
            .Delete
         
            l1 = Split((Columns(Col - 1).Address(, 0)), ":")(0) & "2"
            Dim s1 As String
            s1 = Split((Columns(Col).Address(, 0)), ":")(0) & "2"
            
           
            regex_results = RegExpMatch(Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(1048576, Col)), "Fruit \d+")
            fr_formula = "=AND(EXACT(" & l1 & ", ""New Fruit""), " & regex_results & ")"
            .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=fr_formula
            'CHANGE 1 END
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = "Error"
            .InputMessage = "Editable if 'Fruit = New Fruit'. Please Enter in this format: Fruit 12345"
            .ErrorMessage = "Please Enter in valid format: Fruit 12345 only for New Fruit"
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    Next Col
```

Approach 2:
RegExpMatch

```
Public Function RegExpMatch(input_range As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.pattern = pattern
    regex.ignorecase = False
    regex_matches = regex.Test(Range(input_range).Value)

    res = "True"
    If regex_matches = False Then
        res = "False"
    End If
  RegExpMatch = res
  Exit Function
ErrHandl:
    RegExpMatch = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Validation changes

```
s1 = Split((Columns(Col).Address(, 0)), ":")(0) & "2"
fr_formula = "=AND(EXACT(" & l1 & ", ""NewFR""), EXACT(""" & RegExpMatch(s1, "FR \d+") & """, ""True""))"
```

Comment: "does not work correctly" doesn't give us much information about what's going wrong - can you please expand?

Comment: `regex_results` is a (huge) array - you can't concatenate an array into a string like that.

Comment: @TimWilliams, it is giving the error "Type mismatch". When the function is used in cells in Excel, it does return TRUE or FALSE as expected. Also, when I use the data validation UI tool in excel, it is working as expected. The issue arises only in VBA; this preferably should not be done with the data validation tool. Do you know if there is a better way to use regex in vba?

Comment: Difficult to make suggestions without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is a column of data in the Excel sheet that a user is editing. If it is not in the correct format (ex: AB \d+), there will be an error message, and the user will not be able to enter that data.

Comment: So you want for the "Fruit" column to add DV which says if (cell to left = "New Fruit") and (cell not like "Fruit {numerics here]") then flag error?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event might be a option for data validation.

Comment: Agree using worksheet_change is probably the way to go - it's challenging to use custom formulas in data validation

Comment: @TimWilliams that is correct, but I would like to use regular expressions instead of like if possible.